# D3 transform the scale and keep the position unchanged

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to drag a group of elements in d3, but When the mouse is on the operator I need to scale the group as well.

When I scale the group it changes its position, is it possible to scale it while its position is unchanged in the svg?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nt8q3ha5/) of my work.

```
<svg width="400" height="400" style="background-color: red">

    <g id="op" class="operator">

        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" style="fill: yellow"></circle>

    </g>

</svg>
```

**script.js**

```
d3.selectAll('.operator')
        .on('mouseenter', function () {

            console.log('Mouse Enter');
            d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(2)');

        })
        .on('mouseleave', function () {

            console.log('Mouse Leave');

        })
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('drag', function () {

            d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' +                         d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')');

        })

        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a scale of 2.

If the cx was 50 and cy is 50, then on scale 2 the circle will appear at center cx * scale = 100 and cy * scale=100.

That's the reason why it jumps on scale. Now if you want the circle to be at the same place, you need to do something like this:

```
d3.select(this).select("circle").attr("cx", 50/scale)
d3.select(this).select("circle").attr("cy", 50/scale)
```

Divide by scale this will neutralize the scale effect for the center of the circle.

So post scale the new cx and cy will be 25.

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/49sx1qc9/).

Comment: Well, my actual implementation has couple of circles inside the group. Should I set the centre for all the elements?

Comment: If you are scaling the circle on mouse over then yes you will have to do the reset of cx and cy so that it stays in the same position.

Comment: noted. but I am still looking for a easy solution. :D

Comment: are you scaling all the circles in the group on mouse over? if yse then y didnt you scale teh full group?

Comment: Yes, but they have different cx, cy. also they have couple of images as well.

Comment: hmmm gotcha ur problem..:)

Comment: Are all your objects in the group circles?  If not, then you would need to translate the position back to 0,0 and scale the group, and translate back to the new location.

Comment: Another generic way to handle all the circle in the group for scaling is this https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/49sx1qc9/2/

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis that's a great idea. I will check on that.